# TypeError: imageStream.pipe is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm encountering an issue while using the GetObjectResponse object from the OCI Object Storage library. When trying to use the .pipe() method on the value property of the GetObjectResponse, I receive the following error:

`TypeError: imageStream.pipe is not a function`

**Expected Behavior:**
The .pipe() method should work as expected on the value property, allowing the stream content to be piped to a response object.

**Actual Behavior:**
Encountering the "TypeError: imageStreamValue.pipe is not a function" error when attempting to use .pipe() on the value property.

```js
#oci-object-storage-service.ts

async getImageAsStream(folderName: string, imageName: string): Promise<GetObjectResponse | null> {
    try {
      const authenticationProvider =  this.createAuthenticationProvider();
      const objectStorageClient = new ObjectStorageClient({
        authenticationDetailsProvider: authenticationProvider,
      });
  
      const objectName = folderName + '/' + imageName;
  
      const getObjectRequest = {
        namespaceName: process.env.OCI_NAMESPACE + '',
        bucketName: process.env.OCI_BUCKET_NAME + '',
        objectName: objectName,
      };

  
      const getObjectResponse = await objectStorageClient.getObject(getObjectRequest);

   
  
      if (getObjectResponse) {

        return getObjectResponse;
      }
  
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching image stream:', error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Below is my controller:-

```js
#image.controller.ts 

@get('/image-stream/{folderName}/{imageName}')
  async getImageStream(
    @param.path.string('folderName') folderName: string,
    @param.path.string('imageName') imageName: string,
    @inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const ociResponse = await this.cloudStorageService.getImageAsStream(folderName, imageName);

    if (ociResponse) {
       
        imageStream = ociResponse.value;
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    
        imageStream.pipe(response);
    
    } else {
      response.status(404).send('Image not found');
    }
  }
}
```